# Vimeo tracking in Google Analytics not sending events

Tags: google-analytics, vimeo, event-tracking

I have followed the documentation from Vimeo to track play-events in Google Analytics but no events are being sent.

```
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'MY-ANALYTICS-ID', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="https://extend.vimeocdn.com/ga/MY-VIMEO-ID.js"></script>
```

The Vimeo iframe is not loaded in a modal or anything. It's just a simple iframe copy pasted from Vimeo embed.

It's tracking normal page views but the Vimeo script is not sending any events. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error myself.
In the Vimeo script it basically says something like this:

```
if (window.dataLayer) {
    window.dataLayer.push("", "");
} else if (window.ga) {
    window.ga("", "");
} else if(window.gtag) {
    window.gtag("", "");
}
```

So if Google Tag Manager (dataLayer) is installed you cannot track with ga().

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to track Vimeo in GA and have used several json packages from experts to no avail. so I wonder if that is the problem. Example: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-video-tracking/